# How to set class names dynamically?

Tags: python

I have a function that creates classes derived from it's arguments:

```
def factory(BaseClass) :
    class NewClass(BaseClass) : pass
    return NewClass
```

Now when I use it to create new classes, the classes are all named the same, and the instances look like they have the same type:

```
NewA = factory(ClassA)
NewB = factory(ClassB)
print type(NewA()) # <class __main__.NewClass>
print type(NewB()) # <class __main__.NewClass>
```

Is the proper fix to manually set the `__name__` attribute?

```
NewA.__name__ = 'NewA'
print type(NewA()) # <class __main__.NewA>
```

Are there any other things I should be setting while I'm at it?

Answer (score 67, accepted):

Yes, setting `__name__` is the correct thing to do; you don't need to set anything else to adjust the class name.

For example:

```
def factory(BaseClass) :
    class NewClass(BaseClass): pass
    NewClass.__name__ = "factory_%s" % BaseClass.__name__
    return NewClass
```

`type` is the *wrong* thing to use here. It doesn't let you define classes with [Python's normal class syntax](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html), instead making you set up every class attribute manually. It's used to create classes by hand, e.g. if you have an array of base classes and you want to create a class using it (which you can't do with Python's class syntax). Don't use it here.

Comment: Not correct anymore, nowadays you also need to change __qualname__. See https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3155/

Comment: @TorbenKlein Is it that we need to set both `__qualname__` and `__name__` or just `__qualname__` now?

Comment: Expanded my comment into a full answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54284495/221166

Comment: At least in Python3, ``__qualname__`` (and ``__name__``) can and should be set in the class body directly: ``class NewClass(BaseClass):    __qualname__ = "factory_%s" % BaseClass. __qualname__``. This allows hooks during class creation, such as a metaclass or ``__init_subclass__``, to see the "correct" name.

Answer (score 25):

Updating the answer off Glenn Maynard: Nowadays there is the `__name__` attribute and the `__qualname__` attribute. The first is what you might think; the second is the dotted "path" for nested classes.

In case of "simple" classes both are equal. Just set `__name__` and `__qualname__` to your new name. You should set both attributes, since you cannot be sure at which one 3rd-party code will look.

Now for nested classes, the differences between the two attributes show:

```
class Outer:
    class Inner:
        pass
print(Outer.__name__, Outer.__qualname__)
print(Outer.Inner.__name__, Outer.Inner.__qualname__)
```

prints:

```
Outer Outer
Inner Outer.Inner
```

If you want to change `Outer`'s name, you need to patch three places, namely `Outer.__name__`, `Outer.__qualname__`, `Inner.__qualname__`. For the latter two you need to split and join at the dots correctly.

A final warning: Even if you did all that right, stuff like sphinx, pylint, etc... might still not work 100%. For example the fake name cannot be found in the module namespace as usual; the source cannot be `grep`ped for the class definition; and so on.

Comment: I found that I had to also change `__module__` also to fully emulate the class name.

Comment: If you need to the name as used in `str()`, this is the correct answer.

Comment: What about generated classes, that is, classes that are returned from functions? Should `__qualname__` indicate that those classes have been generated from those specific functions, or is it okay to just set `__qualname__` to whatever you set `__name__` to? Will there be any consequences for doing the latter?

Comment: Unlike other "magic" attributes, ``__qualname__`` doesn't have any effect on the class's behavior. It is only used for introspection, e.g. for logging and docs generation. So in principle you are free to put anything in there. Just setting it as ``__name__`` should do. Or you could put something like ``"<generated>."+__name__`` to indicate that is is dynamically generated.

Answer (score 16):

Check out using the [`type()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#type) function with three arguments. The following code creates a new class "NewA", with `object` as the base type, and no initial attributes.

```
>>> type('NewA', (object,), {})
<class '__main__.NewA'>
```

Comment: Seems a bit clunky if the class definition in NewClass is very long.  I would have to accumulate all the methods into a dictionary (I assume the doc string goes there too, under key `'__doc__'`).

Comment: Also what if the methods in NewClass have to dynamically refer to the methods of BaseClass?

Comment: `type` is for things like creating classes with variable base lists; it's entirely the wrong tool for this.

Comment: @kiyo: In your example code, NewClass had nothing defined other than it's name and base class, so this method would work perfectly well. If your NewClass is going to have actual attributes in it, then yes, changing `__name__` is fine and preferable. Both methods will function equally well, however.

Comment: I get NameError if I access the class created by type(). How can I solve it?

Comment: @Yun The `type()` constructor does not create the name/symbol passed in the first parameter, it only returns an instance of the class created. The first parameter is only used for internals (`.__name__` and `.__qualname__`) and the one-parameter `type()` function.