# Create multiple classes from List of Strings

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, class

I have a list of string as follows:

```
list = ['ContactHandler', 'LogHandler', 'FileHandler', 'SystemHandler', 'WelcomeHandler']
```

I want to use this list to create 5 classes in a for loop. An example of one class is shown below.

```
class WelcomeHandler(BaseHandler):
        def get(self):
            response = HTTPResponse()
            response.write('WelcomeHandler')
            return response
```

Comment: Duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5352781/how-to-set-class-names-dynamically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a dictionary for your classes and define them like this:

```
classes = {}
for name in classlist:
    class Handler(BaseHandler):
        def get(self):
            response = HTTPResponse()
            response.write(self.__class__.__name__)
            return response
    Handler.__name__ = name
    classes[name] = Handler
```

Comment: Can I import these classes from another.py with the given names from the dictionary?

Comment: Not exactly.  You can use `import myfile; WelcomeHandler = myfile.classes['WelcomeHandler']`, though.  (That's assuming that this file is called `myfile.py`.

Answer (score 1):

Make a dictionary mapping the name to the class:

```
classLookup = {
    'ContactHandler': ContactHandler, 
    'LogHandler'    : LogHandler,
    #...
}
```

Then you can instantiate the right class based on the string

```
className = input('what class to instantiate?')
handler = classLookup[className]()
```