# How to pass class keyword arguments with the `type()` built-in function?

Tags: python

The `class` statement takes keyword arguments for various features. For example, the `__init_subclass__` function receives keyword arguments passed at the class declaration:

```py
class A(object):
  def __init_subclass__(cls, **kwargs):
    print(f'{kwargs=}')

class B(A, my_arg=5):
  pass
```

```
kwargs={'my_arg': 5}
```

However, doing so prevents dynamic class creation: The `type` function does not seem to take the `class` keyword arguments. [A factory function does](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5352781/how-to-set-class-names-dynamically), but may conflict with `__init_subclass__` or similar when the factory must modify the class.

I would like to use the `type()` built-in function in its 3-arguments version to dynamically create a class. However, there seems to be no documented way to pass keyword arguments (like `my_arg` in the previous example).

What would be the recommended way of doing it ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The bare `type` is not the equivalent of `class` statements in Python3. Use [`types.new_class`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/types.html#types.new_class) as a functional equivalent of `class` statements.

```py
class B(A, my_arg=5):
  a = 12  # non-trivial class body

B = types.new_class(
    'B',
    # base classes of `class` statement
    bases=(A,),
    # keywords to the `class` statement
    kwds={'my_arg': 5},
    # the class body as a function
    exec_body=lambda body: body.update({'a': 12}),
)
```

Keep in mind that a `class` statement can always be wrapped in a function to allow a parameterised, functional class creation. This also allows to set most special attributes, e.g. the class name via `__qualname__`:

```py
def make_b(my_arg, my_a, name=None):
    class Parameterized_B(A, my_arg=my_arg):
        a = my_a
        if name is not None:
            __qualname__ = name
    return Parameterized_B

B = make_b(5, 12, "B")
```

Comment: I prefer the first way in my case for the meta class to get the right class name at the class creation