# Creating a class that instantiates via a metaclass: how do I create this class with type?

Tags: python, types, metaclass

The creation of a class via declaration of the form

```
class Simple(Base):
    x=0
```

is equivalent, I believe, to using a `type` statement:

```
Simple = type( 'Simple', (Base,), dict( x=0 ) )
```

Is there a `type` statement equivalent to the following declaration?

```
class Simple(Base,metaclass=Meta):
    x=0
    def __init__(self,x):
      self.x = x
```

I've tried

```
def s2_init(self,x): 
  self.x = x

S2 = type( 'Simple', (Base,), dict( x=0, __metaclass__=Meta , __init__=s2_init) )
```

but `Meta` does not get used when `S2` is instantiated (this behaviour, `__metaclass__` being ignored, is as expected from the documentation).

Comment: "is equivalent, I believe, to using a ``type`` statement:" It's not. The call to ``type`` is the very last thing of creating a class.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a way of passing keyword arguments to `__init_subclass__` with the `type()` built-in function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66222211/is-there-a-way-of-passing-keyword-arguments-to-init-subclass-with-the-typ)

Comment: Depending on what you are trying to do, the correct approach is either ``Meta('Simple', (Base,), dict( x=0 ))`` (using the metaclass ``Meta`` instead of ``type``) or ``types.new_class('Simple', (Base,), {'metaclass':Meta}, exec_body=lambda d: d.update(x=0))`` (using ``new_class`` as a functional equivalent of ``class``).

Comment: Thanks @MisterMiyagi : those both solve my problem .. and I'll need to read a bit more about the difference between a `class` declaration and using `type` to generate a class.