# How to create a Python class dynamically with `=` on the subclass argument

Tags: python

Under certain conditions, Python allows the following:

```py
class A(SQLModel, table=True):
    a = 1
```

as used by [sqlmodel](https://sqlmodel.tiangolo.com/#create-a-sqlmodel-model)'s API.

The question: how can we generate the equivalent of the above dynamically,

```py
type("A", (SQLModel, ???), {"a": 1})
```

Comment: You want ``types.new_class``, not ``type``. There's a dupe somewhere...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to pass class keyword arguments with the `type()` built-in function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66222211/how-to-pass-class-keyword-arguments-with-the-type-built-in-function)

Comment: Very quick, not entirely correct answer: `type("A", (SQLModel,), {'a': 1}, table=1)`.

Comment: The full process is described under the [Metaclasses](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#metaclasses) section of the language documentation; `types.new_class` is a convenience function for ensuring *all* the steps in the process are followed, though in many simple cases only the call to the metaclass is necessary.